# Secure Login + salted password storage

Tags: authentication, web, cryptography, authorization

1. I want to have a secure login process where login data are encrypted.
2. Prevent replay attack of the login form.
3. At the same time, I want the password being encrypted and no one can decrypt them.

For 1. I can MD5 the form data.

For 2. I can generate a nonce and hash it together with client password.

For 3. I can use salt stored in DB and save only MD5(password|salt) in DB

Now the problem comes, for 1 and 2, I will be sending MD5(password|nonce) to server, but I am unable to authorize it because I don't have the original password for checking.

Can I archieve 1,2,3 at the same time?

Comment: You want to use MD5 for encryption?
please correct your question

Comment: MD5 is a hashing algorithm

Answer (score 2):

For 1. and 2. Use HTTPS (SSL). It prevents active and passive attacks, replays, keeps the password confidential.

For 3 use a specialized password hash together with a per-user salt. Standard choices are scrypt, bcrypt and PBKDF2. Do a bit of research for the details, we have plenty of related questions here and on security. SE.

Answer (score -2):

For transport security use SSL/TLS. 
For replay protection use CSRF Tokens. 
For secure password storage use keyed hash [something like this.](http://fatfredyy.blogspot.com/2012/12/secure-password-storage.html)

**Edit:** Presented scheme is not insecure, you can read more about this idea in this [post at security.se](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/3289/11283)

Comment: Read a decent article about password hashing. A password guessing attack on single iteration hashes is quite fast. That's why you should use a slow hash construction, such as scrypt, bcrypt or PBKDF2. This increases the cost of breaking a password hash a lot.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I agree that single pass hashing is less secure, than multipass KDF's but it's still regarded as cracking infeasible, and sitll widely used. Not every framework supports KDF's but most of them does support sha256 that's why I proposed it. Plus SHA-256 was a sample hashing function.